# MySQL, procedure will not be called

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a procedure to find the firepower of a class of ships. (The firepower is the number of guns * the displacement cubed)

Relation:

```
Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)
```

What I have tried so far...

```
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE firePower(in className VARCHAR(50), out p int)
-> begin
-> set p = (SELECT numGuns * displacement * displacement * displacement FROM classes
WHERE class = className);
-> end
-> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)

mysql> CALL firePower(Iowa, @p)//
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Iowa' in 'field list'
mysql> SELECT * FROM classes//
+----------------+------+---------+---------+------+--------------+
| class          | type | country | numGuns | bore | displacement |
+----------------+------+---------+---------+------+--------------+
| Bismarck       | bb   | Germany |       8 |   16 |        42000 |
| Iowa           | bb   | USA     |       9 |   16 |        46000 |
| Kongo          | bc   | Japan   |       8 |   14 |        32000 |
| North Carolina | bb   | USA     |       9 |   16 |        37000 |
| Renown         | bc   | Britain |       6 |   15 |        32000 |
| Revenge        | bb   | Britain |       8 |   15 |        29000 |
| Tennessee      | bb   | USA     |      12 |   14 |        32000 |
| Yamato         | bb   | Japan   |       9 |   18 |        65000 |
+----------------+------+---------+---------+------+--------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL firePower(Bismarck, @p)//
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Bismarck' in 'field list'
mysql>
```

My problem is that I cannot seem to call my procedure now...?

Comment: Try adding quotes to the call... ie CALL firePower('Bismarck', @p)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not quoting `Bismarck`in the call, the procedure is interpreting it as a column name. Adding single quotes around it will match against the actual string.

```
mysql> CALL firePower('Bismarck', @p)//
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @BumSkeeter This question remains as *not-answered* since April of 2012. Since this have **worked**, please mark the answer as accepted.